# Get items in array from index 2:3

Tags: javascript

I have an array myArray=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. I need to get items from index 2:3.

In Python this would be:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(my_array[2:3])
```

How can I accomplish this in javascript?

Comment: you can use .slice

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function:

```js
let my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr = my_array.slice(2,3);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.prototype.slice()`(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
let my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(my_array.slice(2,3)) // prints '3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.slice(first_index, last_index)`. Note that the element at `last_index` is not returned, so add 1.

If you want to return `[3, 4]`, use `my_array.slice(2,4)`.
Remember, of course, that array indices are zero-based ;)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice